# accessing a list set in bean in jsp

Tags: jsp, el, jsp-tags

In a bean "Result", an arrayList "tempList" is set.This bean is then set into session.
I have to fetch arrayList elements on JSP page.

I am not getting the way of how to fetch its elements.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSTL `<c:forEach>`:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
 <c:forEach items="${youSessionAttributeName}" var="i">
    Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
 </c:forEach>
```